# Crystal Reports print page to page

Tags: vb.net, printing, crystal-reports, preview, crystal-reports-2010

I am using visual studio 10 with the version of crystal report 13, I have a report with two details, the result of each print are two sheets,

The problem is that I have 26,000 records, and the details (B) result in 52,000 records that are displayed correctly in the preview, but when I click print, the total pages displayed is 32,000! should be 52,000

Comment: Total pages should be 52,000 seems like a lot of pages to me. So is each record its own page or am I wrong here?

Comment: i think He mean 52,000 record not Pages @MrCoDeXeR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right Click on Details in Report 
Details->Paging ->New Page After -> Mark Visible Record  And Define Number of Rows in Each Page